# wxPython - StyledTextCtrl get currently visible lines

Tags: python, performance, wxpython, scintilla

I am still working on my text editor, and now I want to make it run faster. So I thought I may somehow get currently visible text, and parse it as I want. So is there a way to get currently visible lines?

**P.S.** Or maybe there is another way to increase StyledTextCtrl's performance? Thanks.

Comment: What is the performance issue, and why do you think parsing the currently visible text will help? Are you trying to write a custom lexer?

Comment: @ekhumoro, if it helps, yes. The problem is, when I scrool my text (like 5k lines), my CPU is working hard, up to 60%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GetFirstVisibleLine()` to determine the first visible line. Lines are numbered starting at zero.

Use `LinesOnScreen()` to determine how many lines are visible on the screen.

You can use `GetLine(line)` to get a string of an individual line.